# How feasible is it to scan CORONA satellite imagery in the National Archives?

Tags: satellite, aerial-photography, photos, usgs, historical-imagery

I'm building a dataset of several hundred historical CORONA satellite images for a research project. I know that one can request these images from the [US Geological Survey](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-declassified-data-declassified-satellite-imagery-1), but new scans cost $30 apiece, and with so many images this quickly becomes expensive.

One alternative would be to scan the images myself in a trip to the National Archives. The CORONA photos are held in the [National Archives Cartographic Reading Room](https://www.archives.gov/research/cartographic/aerial-photography/satellite-photography), which says that aerial film scanners are available for use.

Has anyone tried scanning these photos at the National Archives before, and how does the quality of the scanners compare to those used by the USGS? **In other words, how feasible would it be to scan these images myself in the National Archives, instead of requesting them from the USGS?**

Comment: You might want to contact someone at the Archives to see if this is even possible.  The original film was long continuous strips. The readers available might not be compatible with that film.

Comment: On the National Archives site, they mention that "The full images cannot be scanned on these scanners due to the size of the photographs, but separate images can be stitched together to create the full image".

Comment: $30 is looking more and more attractive. I doubt they're making a profit on the deal. if it takes you 2-3 hours to scan and stitch the scans back together, you'd be working at under the District's minimum wage.

Comment: That's a really good point.